# Python Program running fine on Spyder but giving error while executing from cmd

Tags: python, spyder, face-recognition, opencv

I have the below code, which runs fine on spyder but when i execute it through cmd, i am getting error.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os 

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

recognizer.read('D:/MachineLearning/FaceDetection/site- 
/Dataset/trainer/trainer.yml')

cascadePath = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Ana3\\envs\\py35_try2\\Lib\\site- 
packages\\cv2\\data\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

id = 0

names = ['None', 'John', 'Sam'] 

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(3, 640) # set video widht
cam.set(4, 480) # set video height

minW = 0.1*cam.get(3)
minH = 0.1*cam.get(4)


while True:
ret, img =cam.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale( 
    gray,
    scaleFactor = 1.2,
    minNeighbors = 5,
    minSize = (int(minW), int(minH)),
   )

for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
    id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])

    if (confidence < 100):
        id = names[id]
        confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
    else:
        id = "unknown"
        confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))

    cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x+5,y-5), font, 1, (255,255,255), 2)
    cv2.putText(img, str(confidence), (x+5,y+h-5), font, 1, (255,255,0), 1)  

cv2.imshow('camera',img) 

k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
if k == 27:
    break
print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am receiving the below error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "FaceRecognition.py", line 14, in 
>       recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
>   AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'

I am receiving this error message because of the below line of code , but i am not sure how to solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

Thanks.